Issues with Relay Control in STM32 Applications
Recently, I've been experiencing frequent issues with relay control using STM32 microcontrollers. My relays typically operate with a 12V DC coil voltage and are used to switch 230V loads. For instance, in circuits where I control a motor directly with a relay, the STM32 sometimes opens and closes unexpectedly, occasionally gets stuck, or even enters a hard fault state. These issues occur randomly and at unexpected times. For example, while testing the boards at home or in the office, I often do not encounter any problems. However, when I take the board to the application site, the STM32 behaves correctly sometimes but fails at other times, usually during relay activation and deactivation.
I try to keep the STM32 as far away from the relays as possible, but even with a single relay operation, I experience similar issues. Consequently, many of my boards have become unusable. I would like to seek your advice on this matter. What should I pay attention to in STM32 circuits involving relays? Can you provide examples of robust and durable relay driving circuits? What conditions should I consider in the software for relay control?
I want this to be a general discussion because I have seen hundreds of people online facing similar issues. I hope this content will be beneficial to many.
Thank you.
EDIT:


Most likely the contacts arcing zaps the MCU to a state it does not work. But we can't see your schematics.

@Justme i just added sorry

Why do you use the extra PNP? It lowers the voltage at the relais and uses about 100mA additional current through its base.

Could also be a layout issue with the 230VAC parts.

This is exactly why people use much more expensive PLCs instead of cobbing together development boards or Arduinos. The problem is some combination of the noise from switching, layout and other EMC considerations. The relays you are using are not terrible, chances are the problem lies elsewhere. Good protection on all seemingly unrelated inputs and outputs, shielding, and good layout on a multilayer board..

You only need Q1  to drive the relay. Q4 is superfluous. How did you formulate this drive circuit? Nothing specific to the STM32 in regards to the core issue. It’s more likely how you’re powering the circuit and the wiring layout. STM32 are popular with whitegoods manufacturers where they frequently switch motors and solenoids.
